# TMF8701 ToF Distance Sensor from AMS with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to send a command to the command register from my TMF8701 sensor from AMS with Python code from a Raspberry Pi. I have to of these sensors connected to the I2C Bus of the Raspberry Pi. One for channel 1 and one for channel 0. I am writing the 0x10 register with 0x0A and trying to do the factory calibration. But after this command is written, the 0x1E register does not have the correct value. I also tried to write another command, for example 0x0B, but also the 0x1E register does not return the correct value. Can anyone help me?

```
import smbus
from time import sleep


CMD_DATA0=0x0F
CMD_DATA1=0x0E
CMD_DATA2=0x0D
CMD_DATA3=0x0C
CMD_DATA4=0x0B
CMD_DATA5=0x0A
CMD_DATA6=0x09
CMD_DATA7=0x08
CMD_DATA8=0x07
CMD_DATA9=0x06
#14 Byte
FACTORY_CALIBRATION=0x28



class tmf8701_distanceSensor():
    # by default, this assumes that the device is at 0x41
    def __init__(self, channel, address=0x41):
        self.address = address
        self.channel = channel
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(self.channel)
        
        #self.reset()
        sleep(1)  # wait 1 sec
        self.setup()
        
    
    #def reset(self):
        #0x10 - command
    
    #factoryCalibrationValue=""
    def factoryCalibration(self):
        sleep(2)
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x10, [0x0A])
        #while (self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E))!=0x0A:
            #sleep(1)
            #print("while")
        sleep(10)
        #print("factory calibration")
        #print(str(int(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E))), str(int(0x0A)))
        #Factory Calibration begins 0x20 und dann 14 byte
        block=self.bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x20, 14)
        print(block)
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x2c))
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x2d))
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x01))
    
    
    """def bootloaderReadyForNewCommand(self):
        #CMD_STAT register - 0x0 - READY
        #0x10-0xFF - busy - davor error und gut ! 
        read0x10Register=self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x10)
        if read0x10Register == 0:
            return("ready")
        elif read0x10Register < int(0x10):
            return read0x10Register
        else:
            print("try again later??? ")
            return "busy"""""
        
    def readResults(self):
        print("erst 0x20")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x20)) 
        print("dann 0x1D")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1D))  
        print("dann 0x20")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x20)) 
        print("zuletzt 0x1E")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E)) 
         
    def setDeviceInStandBy(self):
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0xE0, [0x00])
        
    def setup(self):
        ###bootloader settings:
        if not self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x00)==0x80:
            self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x00, [0x80])
        #wake up sensor
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0xE0, [0x01])
        sleep(3)
        ###
        read0xE0Register=self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0xE0)
        print("register 0xE0, if 65 => perfect!")
        print(read0xE0Register)
        ### app0 settings:
        
        if not self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x00)==0xC0:
            self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x00, [0xC0])
            
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x10, [0x0B])    
        #read serial number
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x10, [0x47])
        #while (self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E))!=0x0A:
            #sleep(1)
            #print("while")
        sleep(10)
        print("serialdata")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E))
        block=self.bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x28, 3)
        print(block)
        #print("factory calibration")
        #print(str(int(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x1E))), str(int(0x0A)))
        #Factory Calibration begins 0x20 und dann 14 byte
        #block=self.bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.address, 0x1E, )
        #print(block)
        
        self.factoryCalibration()
        print("currently running SW register: 128 = 0x80 - bootloader, 192 = 0xC0 - App0 ")
        print(self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, 0x00))
        ###algorithm state and factory calibration is provided
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA7, [0x03])
        ###
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA6, [0x23])
        ### no GPIO control used
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA5, [0x00])
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA4, [0x00])
        ### needs to be always 00
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA3, [0x00])
        ### repetition period in ms 64 hex = 100ms
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA2, [0x64])
        ### needs to be always ff
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA1, [0xFF])
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address, CMD_DATA0, [0xFF])
```

```
import csv,os
import numpy as np
import threading
#import max30102
import TMF8701_distanceSensor
import datetime
import time
from numpy import number


print("start")
print("sensor finger")
sensorTMF_finger=TMF8701_distanceSensor.tmf8701_distanceSensor(0)
#sensorTMF_finger.factoryCalibration()

print("sensor hand")
sensorTMF_hand=TMF8701_distanceSensor.tmf8701_distanceSensor(1)
#sensorTMF_hand.factoryCalibration()
number=0
while number<10:
    print("hand")
    #sensorTMF_hand.readResults()
    print("finger")
    sensorTMF_finger.readResults()
    number=number+1
```

The output I get on the Raspberry Pi looks like that:

```
start
sensor finger
register 0xE0, if 65 => perfect!
65
serialdata
0
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0
0
16
currently running SW register: 128 = 0x80 - bootloader, 192 = 0xC0 - App0
192
sensor hand
register 0xE0, if 65 => perfect!
65
serialdata
0
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0
0
16
currently running SW register: 128 = 0x80 - bootloader, 192 = 0xC0 - App0
192
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
hand
finger
erst 0x20
0
dann 0x1D
0
dann 0x20
0
zuletzt 0x1E
0
```